# Position of controller not updated after camera moving with teleport-controls in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr, htc-vive

I use teleport-controls in A-Frame.

After moving of the camera with teleport-controls is the model of Vive controller moved. But the attribute "position" of controller element is not updated.

If I build a box at the position of controller after the moving, the position of new box is not at the new position of the controller, but the old position of the controller.

Therefore I try to set the 'position' of controller as the "newPosition" from event "teleported", but it doesn't work.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/21f0cfd9-2fa0-49f3-910b-aedb91df3d3b

Maybe has someone idea about it?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. The controllers as its children will move with the rig when moved by `teleport-controls`. No need to set the position manually. More elaboration will help.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question to describe the problem.

If I build a box at the position of controller after the moving, the position of new box is not at the new position of the controller, but the old position, before the moving, of the controller.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos I have solved the problem. I use the relative position as absolute position before. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool. Nice to hear. Can you answer the question so others can learn in the future?

Comment: Sure, I did it. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I use the relative position as absolute position before.